# collect on hadoopFile RDD returns duplicate results

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read avro file like below

```
val rdd = sc.hadoopFile(
  classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat[MyAvroRecord]],
  classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper[MyAvroRecord]],
  classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable])(avropath)


val collectedData = rdd.collect()

for (s <- collectedData){
  println(s)
}
```

However when I print the same it gives duplicate values.Is there a way to get valid values from RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `rdd.map(_._1.datum)` before doing the collect.

From the [SparkContext API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html):

> '''Note:''' Because Hadoop's RecordReader class re-uses the same Writable object for each record, directly caching the returned RDD or directly passing it to an aggregation or shuffle operation will create many references to the same object. If you plan to directly cache, sort, or aggregate Hadoop writable objects, you should first copy them using a map function.